# Prevent call taking over screen during navigation

Tags: calls, navigation

I want to prevent call taking over my screen during navigation (Google Maps or Waze).

During navigation I dial / receive calls by my car controls, also see everything there, so don't need to see call information on phone (however seeing it for a few seconds before automatically switching back to navigation would also be fine).

I've already tried looking for solutions, but all what I've found was just workarounds (switch to "do not disturb" ...)

I've a Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016) with Android 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is I know it can be done as a friend just has a little box with call coming in and it leaves a small box with the map in the corner. You would think that there would just be a simple button to swipe in settings but no, nothing. Come on google make life easy for people, please.

Comment: I've updated to android 8 and now I've it too. So maybe depends on the version..

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried much other then [Macrodroid - PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)

Steps:-

1. Install app
2. Add new macro
3. In triggers search and select "Call Active" (also check any contact, any number, non contact, unknown caller)
4. In actions search and select "Press Back Button" (would need accessibility permission)

Note:- I am using Rooted(but this Particular macro shouldn't need Root) Moto G5+(Almost stock Android N 7.0 that Google provides) and samsung uses customised version so give it a try
 
It should work but still can't say anything without trying

Also Note:-
 
The time you want to use call screen you will have to disable the macro or you can also create a Toggler Macro (to toggle it on/off)

Do report back

Comment: Thanks! Definitely a good suggestion.  Unfortunately pressing back button requires accessibility which is not allowed by my company app.

Comment: You don't even want the screen to turn on when a call arrives , am i right ?    and what should happen when you make outgoing call?                         Should screen stay off ?

Comment: Screen is on, I'm using navigation. I want to keep seeing that instead of call screen. If it switches to call screen for a few seconds that's isn't an issue.

Comment: Would it be ok if you get minimal display for e.g., just call answer button nothing else?